# Which prediction model should we use to predict the list of colleges for a student

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

I have a training data set containing College names,student rank, branch, college cutoff. Which prediction model should I use to predict the list of colleges a student will get admission in according to his rank, college cutoff and the branch?

I am new to machine learning.

I expect the output to display a list of colleges in which a student can be admitted instead of displaying if a college is allocated to a student.

Comment: Nearly all or most machine learning approaches fit your purpose. you can use neural networks, PGMs ot Naive Bayes classifier, etc. To find the one that fits your purpose best the best way is to start studying about machine learning methods.

Comment: Probably you find a better answer on other sites of this forum, try it here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be treated as a multi class classification problem where every college will become a class. You can use a simple random forest model and predict the class probabilities for every student record. Since you are using probabilities, the model will return the list of college along with the probability. Set a probability threshold and take the college above that threshold as your result.

Answer (score 0):

This is a multiclass classification problem. If you are new, I suggest use tree based models such as random forest classifier (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) or try Xgboost if you are not getting good enough results from random forest. They are easy to use and perform nicely in multi-class classification problems. They will also give you feature importance easily that will help you to explain your model as well.